# How can I get list of currently resolved Spring Boot application properties?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In Spring Boot we can expose with the actuator [two endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints) with the properties:

- configprops
- env

[image]

The first returns a scan of all the `@ConfigurationProperties` classes and the second returns the environment object snapshot.

What if I want to see **currently resolved spring boot properties under the currently enabled profiles**, for example as I would call in runtime:

```kotlin
val baz = environemnet.getProperty("foo")
```

Assuming `foo` can be in N sources: environment variables, bootstrap, spring cloud config etc.

But in a particular state of the application we actually do not know which value has been resolved, we always assume based on our knowledge of the documentation (and usually we do not duplicate them because we do not want to think about the order of precedence).

How can I do it?

The best would be to have an actuator endpoint that resolves all the currently active properties.

Another practical example would be:

- I do not remember a property
- I want to get a hint from the current application runtime as we do in IntelliJ Idea, but in the runtime
- I list current, find my
- I can change it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `env` endpoint can [return details for an individual property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#env.single-property). A `GET` request to `/actuator/env/foo` will tell you the value of `foo`, the property source in which the value was found, and information about the other property sources where `foo` may exist but had lower precedence.

I think it's also worth noting that `/actuator/env` returns the property sources in order of precedence. You could create the list of properties and their values with some processing of the response on the client side. Iterate through the property sources in order and only add a property if it hasn't already been seen.

Comment: thank you Andy, it's sorted by order of precedence then